# Round Function in SQl

Tags: sql, sql-server

select Round((10*100)/115,0)

Result : 8

But Result : 8.69

But i want to display 9

I tried below query also, but result is same..

select Round((10*100)/115,0)

Please solve my prob....

Thanks

Comment: Most likely this is a data-typing (integer division) problem but which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: are you using  Round((10*100)/115,0) as int data type then it will round off to 8 but if you value is of decimal or numeric data type then you will get the result 9 by using ceiling

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```
declare @n decimal(4,1)
select @n = 8.69

select case when PARSENAME(@n,1)>=5 then ceiling(@n) else floor(@n) end
```

**idea is if the number after point is greater than 5  then  go to upper value else go to lower one**

Comment: Its giving same result 8, but i want to display 9

Comment: @user2515629 i think the value you are converting is of int data type thats why ceiling function is not returning 9 ....

Answer (score 0):

If your database is oracle then the following function you can use..

For result 9 use ceil function and  For result 8 use floor function

```
select ceil(8.69) val from dual;

  select floor(8.69) val from dual;
```

Comment: nee d to display result in sql server

Answer (score 0):

for upper value you can use Ceil function and for lower value you can use floor function in oracle as below

```
select ceil(8.69) Upper_val,floor(8.69) Lower_val from dual;
```

Comment: yup @love grover, might be at same time :)

Answer (score 0):

It returns an integer.  Try to convert it to a decimal before calculation

Eg.

```
select Round((10*100)/115,0)
```

change to

```
select Round((10.0*100)/115,0)
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

If Its SQL Server please do try this:

```
SELECT CEILING(10.1) AS UpperValue, FLOOR(10.6) AS LowerValue, 
Round(CAST((CAST(10 AS float) * CAST(100 AS float)) / CAST(115 AS float) AS float), 0)
AS YourValue, Round((10*100)/115,0) AS YourOldValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's happening:

Even before using ROUND Function

```
SELECT 1000/115 /* the result is 8 */
```

and try this

```
SELECT ROUND(1000.0/15, 0) /* the result is 9.000000 */
```

and if use this

```
SELECT CEILING(1000.0/115) /* the result is 9 */
```

so basically before call any function the result is 8.

you can use this:

```
SELECT ROUND(CONVERT(decimal, 1000) / 115, 0)
```

or simply this:

```
SELECT ROUND(1000.0/15, 0)
```